# Twilio Video’s new Rooms API for business collaboration apps

Tags: webrtc, twilio

I need to build a Business collaboration apps using the new Twilio Video’s new Rooms API. It uses a traditional calling model, where one user “rings” another user and waits for them to answer. However, I cannot find any "ringing" API in SDK. I was wondering how the Video’s new Rooms API gives (can be used) the ability to build such a call model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) does not have a "ringing" API so this is left up to you to develop using native platform notifications.

If you have a user that wants to call another user on your platform, then I would have the user create and join a room and then send a push notification to the other user which includes the room ID for them to join. Then when that user receives and opens the notification they can instantly join the room too.

Comment: Thanks, my issue with this approach is that the room is not secure. in tokbox for example, each room has a access list. Only a user who has an appropriate permission can join the room. In your approach, (assume) a hacker by knowing the room id can join the room (I think so). I appreciate your comment. Thanks

Comment: You could use a uuid identifier for rooms which would be practically impossible to guess.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thank you